# Calling class object with variable count of arguments

Tags: javascript, function, class, arguments, prototype

I'm making my own jQuery-like library for a very specific task. (dont want to use jquery, to be closer to native js).

I need a solution to call class with and without agruments, in my case - certain selector.

What I've ment - class has to work in both ways:

```
myclass.function();
```

and:

```
myclass(selector).function();
```

Initialization of class looks like this

```
(function(window){
var myclass = function( selector ){
        return new myclass.model.build( selector );
    };

myclass.model = myclass.prototype = {
    constructor: myclass,
    myfunction: function(){
        alert("some function's alert");
    }
};

myclass.model.build = function( selector ){
    if( !selector )
        return this;
    /* Picking objects by selector */
};

window.myclass = myclass;
return myclass;
})(window);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/q0rc32h7/)***

There are a few ways to accomplish this. Here is a common way, which is to setup an instance of a local function ("class") that has its prototype configured as an object for extensibility and has properties attached to it as an object as well.

```js
//use window and document shortcut
(function(win,doc){
 //setup local function in order to extend
 var jakeWeary = function(selector){
  //force an instance to be returned when referenced
  return new jakeWeary.fun.start(selector);        
 };
 //allow prototype to be extended by referencing fun
 jakeWeary.fun = jakeWeary.prototype = {
  constructor : jakeWeary,
  //use passed values to query
  start : function(selector){
   //query against present document
   var nodes = doc.querySelectorAll(selector);
   //mimic an array of matched elements
   for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length;i++){
    this[i] = nodes[i];       
   }
   //return self for chaining
   return this;     
  }
 };
 //extend function object in order to be used without calling instance
 jakeWeary.div = function(content){
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = content;
  return div; 
 };
 //expose
 win.jakeWeary = win.jk = jakeWeary;
})(window,document)

//call instance to match the selector `.d`
var $ = jakeWeary('.d');//lets use a fun variable like $ for this
//reference the third matched element, and then append a div created from a function on the
//jakeWeary function object
$[2].appendChild(jk.div("<p>Reinventing the wheel</p>"));
```

```html
<div id="i">i</div>
<div class="d">d</div>
<div class="d">d</div>
<div class="d">d</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your example made me realise, how it really work. In jq there's an .extend function, which includes function right into the function object but jq.fn. Didn't realise this before.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want the non-instance call to generate a default instance and then be applied to it?

```
var Foo = (function () {
    // set up constructor
    var Foo = function () {
        this.fizz = 'buzz';
    };
    Foo.prototype = Object.create(null);
    // instance version
    Foo.prototype.bar = function () {return 'this.fizz is ' + this.fizz;};
    // non-instance version
    Foo.bar = function () {return Foo.prototype.bar.apply(new Foo(), arguments);};
    return Foo;
}());

Foo.bar(); // "this.fizz is buzz"
```